# How to use two github accounts on the same computer?

Tags: github

I've followed the steps from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574 .

But at the time pusing I'm getting this following error:

```
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git remote add new_origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git push new_origin master
ERROR: Permission to RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git denied to railsfactory-riya.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the hostname alias **github-company** instead of github.com.

```
remote add new_origin git@github-company:RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git
```

Comment: riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git remote add origin1 https://github-personal/RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git push origin1 masterfatal: unable to access 'https://github-personal/RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git/': Could not resolve host: github-personal
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$

Comment: Fix config file.

Comment: #railsfactory-riya account
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa


#RiyaKapuria account
Host github-personal
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

Comment: riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git remote add test_origin https://github-personal:RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$ git push test_origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github-personal:RiyaKapuria/ReduxForm.git/': Could not resolve host: github-personal
riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/ReduxForm$